# Biholomorphic map between the unit disk and $\{{z\in \mathbb{C}}|Im(z)>0, Re(z)>0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have some problems in solving this exercise.

I have to find the Moebius transformation $T$ such that $T(1)=0$, $T(i)=1$, $T(-1)=\infty$ and then, with the help of this $T$, I have to find a biholomorphism between the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ and $\{{z\in \mathbb{C}}|Im(z)>0, Re(z)>0\}$.

I have found $T$:

$T(z)=(z-1)/(z+1)$ and I know that $T$ maps the circle to the real line. How can I use these facts to determine the wanted biholomorphism?
thanks for the help!

Comment: Hint: Think of $z^2$ and/or $\sqrt{z}$...

Comment: @Lukas Geyer Thanks for the help!...My $T$ maps the unit disk to the upper half-plane, and so $\sqrt{T}$ is the wanted biholomorphism...Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your $T$, $T(i)= \frac {i-1}{i+1} = (i-1)^2/(-2) \neq 1$ . The map will be $T(z)=\frac{(z-z_1)(z_2-z_3)}{(z-z_3)(z_2-z_1)}$. Now put $z_1=1, z_2=i,z_3=-1$.

To do the next problem, Hint is think using connectedness.

Comment: Many thanks for the correction!